# What does the "which" refer to?

Tags: clauses

1. Sentence:

   > **A** arises from xxx, as distinct from **B** *which* is associated with xxx.
2. My further question is:

What are the differences between "**,** which" and "which"?

Thanks!

Comment: Refer to B in this sentences.

Comment: The clause after **which** looks like a dependant clause so no comma is required. In this case we could as easily use **that** instead of **which**.

Answer (score 1):

1. The word "which" refers to B.
2. When it is nonrestrictive — when you could take the which clause out and the meaning of the sentence would be unaltered — it takes a comma before it. ... it is not the words which and that that determine whether there is a comma; it is the restrictive or nonrestrictive nature of the clauses they begin.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Which* refers to B. In general, pronouns such as *which* refer to the latest noun in the sentence, in order to make more sense and because it's the last noun you have in mind. If you want to refer to something before that, you'll use expressions such as *the former* compared to *the latter*.
2. Here I don't think the comma changes the meaning of the sentence, just its rhythm. By saying ", which", you put a bit more emphasis on **B**.